# How to find and replace text in a file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd, special-characters

I have an existing file named client.props, I need to create a batch script to read the document and find `root=` and replace it with `root=path_of_file`. I have used the below mentioned script:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "search=root="
set "replace=root=%~dp0"
set "textFile=client.props"
set "textFile1=client1.props"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile1%" ') do 
(
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%textFile1%" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

I am not that great in batch scripts, kindly help me out with this. If file is available in `F:\temp\file\client.props` with one of the line starts with `root=` then the batch should modify it as `root=F:\temp\file`.

Before:

> ```
> root=
> ```

After:

> ```
> root=F:\temp\file
> ```

Comment: The `(` after `do ` must be in the same line as `do `!

Answer (score 0):

The `=` sign cannot be used within the sub-string replacement syntax `!line:%search%=%replace%!`, because the `=` separates the search string and the replacement string.

You could change your `for /F` loop so that it splits every line at the `=` character and checks the left part against `root` and the right one against being empty:

```cmd
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "search=root="
set "replace=root=%~dp0"
set "textFile=client.props"
set "textFile1=client1.props"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile1%" ') do (
    >>"%textFile1%" (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ("%%i") do (
            if /i "%%a="=="%search%" (
                if "%%b"=="" (
                    echo(%replace%
                ) else (
                    echo(%%i
                )
            ) else (
                echo(%%i
            )
        )
    )
)
```

As you can see there is not even delayed expansion necessary. This approach however fails if there is a line like `=root==`, because leading delimiters are ignored and subsequent delimiters are treated as one. To do a case-sensitive search string comparison, remove the `/i` option from the `if` command line.

Note that the replaced line is terminated with a `\`, like `root=F:\temp\file\`, for example.

Comment: is there a way to completely delete the line containing the text/starts with using some wildcard search and we construct our own line

Comment: You mean to delete the line containing or beginning with `root=`? what about `if /i not "%%a"=="%search%" echo(%%i` instead of the entire `if` block then?